# What should be our standard tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

What tags should we define for the main site?

What tags should we define for meta?

Comment: Meta has standard tags already.

Answer (score 9):

This isn't something we need to discuss. Tags will *just appear* as people create, edit, and remove them. Besides, there's no way to create a tag without asking a question - so unless you have a question for every tag proposed in this kind of discussion, we can't do anything about them.

Comment: I was thinking more about some standard tags: `story-identification`, `plot-hole`, `literary-analysis`

Comment: @Gallifreian If people want them, they'll turn up. We don't need to identify what we need now.

Comment: @Gallifreian There's no need to anticipate problems or create a catch-all "what tags do we need" thread in this format. It is better to let things evolve organically, then if you see a problem that is becoming prevalent across the site, that's the time to raise a meta discussion to work it out.

Comment: @RobertCartaino  -  I see. You're probably right.

Comment: I'm tempted to quote Shog9's standard spiel about tags which is highly sensible and very useful, but i'm too lazy. Hopefully Shog himself will sign on to the site and say it :)