# What are the recommended literary term tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

This question is slightly different from other tag related questions, in that I'm asking which tags the site would benefit from, when viewed from subject matter expertise perspective.

On SciFi this was easy - there are really very few generic SME trade terms that could be used universally.

However, literary analysis is a scholarly discipline with established terminology and methodology and common term dictionary, and when asking questions that involve literary analysis, it is my opinion that having access to a well defined formal set of terms would benefit question askers when tagging.

Things like [character-analysis](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-analysis).

The rules for this Q&A (unless it gets downvoted to oblivion because people hate the idea):

- Any proposed tag has to be based on demonstrably common expert term.
- One tag proposal per answer
- If possible, find a question where the tag would apply. This helps both in illustrating its usage, AND later in creating one.
- Positively voted proposed tags will (1) get created and (2) Their answer will be flagged for deletion and incorporated into a summary "these are the tags we created so far" answer.

Comment: @CMs - if you don't object to this post, I would codially request that it be tagged as "featured" to attract attention.

Answer (score 5):

Just quoting Robert Cartaino here:

> [There's no need to anticipate problems or create a catch-all "what tags do we need" thread in this format. It is better to let things evolve organically, then if you see a problem that is becoming prevalent across the site, that's the time to raise a meta discussion to work it out.](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/what-should-be-our-standard-tags/7#comment7_7)

So let's tackle it case by case.